Transpose a rolling set of values in a column into a single value in a cell
I am having troubles with a data transformation I am trying to do.  I have a column of data (Ex. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)I want to create a new column that looks back n rows and concatenates the values into a new value, preferably an integer.   For example, if the lookback window is 3 in my example, the new column would be Nan, Nan, 123, 234,345,456,567,678,789.
So far, here is a bit of code that I tried where n is the lookback window and Streak is the dataframe with the values I am looking to combine into a new value (streakHistory):
def getStreakHistory(Streak, n=20):
    streakHistory= ""
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
         streakHistory=str(streakHistory) + str(Streak["Streak"].shift(x))
    return streakHistory

df["Streak History"] = getStreakHistory(Streak)

This seems to run an error because streakHistory is a string.  I have seen other options where you transpose into other cells, but I want all of the values to be combined and entered into 1 cell.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I also looked into a join, but that seems to be similar to a standard table join and not really the same as what I was looking at unless I am overlooking a particular functionality of it.

Please provide an actual [mre] (input + expected output)

One option would be to use numpy's sliding_window_view combined with agg:
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as svw

df = pd.DataFrame({'Streak': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
N = 3

df['Streak History'] = (pd.DataFrame(svw(df['Streak'].astype(str), N),
                                     index=df.index[N-1:])
                          .agg(''.join, axis=1)
                       )

Output:
   Streak Streak History
0       1            NaN
1       2            NaN
2       3            123
3       4            234
4       5            345
5       6            456
6       7            567
7       8            678
8       9            789

Numeric variant:
df['Streak History'] = pd.Series((svw(df['Streak'], N)
                                  *(10**np.arange(N-1, -1, -1))).sum(1),
                                    index=df.index[N-1:])

Output:
   Streak  Streak History
0       1             NaN
1       2             NaN
2       3           123.0
3       4           234.0
4       5           345.0
5       6           456.0
6       7           567.0
7       8           678.0
8       9           789.0


import pandas as pd
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv
import numpy as np

data = {'Streak': np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
lookback = 3
aa =[ ''.join(str(val) for val in row  ) 
      if any(row) else np.nan
      for row in swv(df['Streak'].astype(int).values,lookback)
    ] 
print(aa)#['123', '234', '345', '456', '567', '678', '789']

df['Streak_History'] = [np.nan]*(lookback -1) + [
''.join(str(val) for val in row)
if any(row)
else np.nan
for row in swv(df['Streak'].astype(int).values,lookback)    
]

print(df)
"""
  Streak Streak_History
0       1            NaN
1       2            NaN
2       3            123
3       4            234
4       5            345
5       6            456
6       7            567
7       8            678
8       9            789
"""

method 2 :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Streak': np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
lookback = 3
def f(row):
    if row.name < lookback -1 :return np.nan
    else:
        aa = ''.join(df['Streak'].iloc[row.name - lookback +1 : row.name +1 ].astype(str))    
    print(aa)
    return aa
    
df['Streak_History'] = df.apply(f,axis=1)
print(df)    

